# Convert SQL Server CE 4 database to SQL Server 2008 Express without Visual Studio Pro edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, database-migration

I'm mainly a front-end developer but do a lot of CMS configuration stuff too. I have a CMS which is set up in a development environment using SQL Server CE 4. I'd like to move this into production using SQL Server Express 2008. However, I'm having huge difficulty in migrating the database from CE to 2008.

I've tried Webmatrix, but it just seems to timeout silently and lock up the destination database (the data isn't huge - around 50Mb).  I've also tried this: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/ but it requires either command-line skills (which I just don't have - I've tried but haven't a clue what I'm doing) or Visual Studio Pro edition - which is around £800. It works using SQL Server Management Studio, but only with SQLCE3.5, not 4.0. I can't justify the price of Visual Studio Pro to convert a freely available database format to another freely available database format.

Does anyone know of any way that someone without command-line skills or a full VS license can do this conversion?

Thanks for any help folks - I'm spending so much time on this :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

But the **excellent** SQL Server CE Toolbox on Codeplex also has a stand-alone GUI edition!

> **Project Description**
>   *SQL Server Compact Toolbox is a Visual Studio 2010
>   Pro or higher add-in (for 3.5/4.0) **and standalone app (for 4.0)**, that
>   adds **scripting, import, export, migrate**, rename, run script, manage
>   replication and more to your SQL Server Compact Data Connections in VS
>   Server Explorer.*

Sounds to me like exactly what you're looking for!

[See the download section](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/69910) - no Visual Studio needed, no command-line skills either - you just need to be able to read a screen and operate a mouse - that's all! :-)

Comment: I can just about operate a mouse, so that looks like the solution, thanks marc_s